# Rollback when retrieving datatable through DataAdapter

Tags: rollback, dataadapter

I have several methods to connect to a SQL Server database. One of them is for retrieving a datatable through a stored procedure. In some instances I use this one where the stored procedure does an actual UPDATE to the database and at the end I just want to retrieve multiple values back, hence retrieving a datatable instead of an output parameter.

I noticed that if an error happens during the UPDATE statement, there is no automatic rollback.

So, I've added the ROLLBACK function in my CATCH statement:

```
 Public Function StoredProcReturnTable(ByVal colParameters As Collection, _
 ByVal strProcName As String, ByVal strTableName As String, _
 ByVal strServer As String, ByVal strDatabase As String) As Data.DataTable

    Dim cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cm As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim objParameter As SqlClient.SqlParameter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    Try
        With cm
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout
            .CommandText = strProcName
            For Each objParameter In colParameters
                .Parameters.Add(objParameter)
            Next
             cn = GetCN(strServer, strDatabase)
            .Connection = cn
            cm.Transaction = cn.BeginTransaction
            da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cm)
            da.Fill(ds)
            cm.Transaction.Commit()
            ds.Tables(0).TableName = strTableName
            Return ds.Tables(0) 
     End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        cm.Transaction.Rollback()
        Throw ex
    Finally
        Close(cn)
    End Try
End Function
```

When testing the stored procedure with an exception, I noticed that my Debug Output window shows:

> Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill'
>   Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill'

I confirmed that the rollback was working, but I am worried that because of those messages that I am doing something wrong? I don't get these messages when using ExecuteNonQuery() for my regular INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE stored procedures.